# Show output using dotnet core 1.1 and xunit unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, xunit

I've fount creating unit tests a super easy way to try out code in Visual Studio over the years.  I was able to get the same type of unit tests to work with .NET core 1.1 in VS 2017 by creating a `Visual C#/.NET Core/Unit Test Project (.NET Core)` project, then adding `xunit` and `xunit.runner.visualstudio` nuget packages.

The only problem is that I no longer see the 'Output' link when the test is run to see what I wrote to the console.  I can use `Trace.WriteLine` from the `System.Diagnostics` package instead and see the output in the `Output` window of Visual Studio, but seeing the output associated with each test run is easier and more useful.

Is there a way to get that to display with my setup or is there a different setup I could use?

***Edit***

@ilya's solution works, but I have to re-write all my tests, removing `[TestClass]` and replacing `[TestMethod]` with `[Fact]`, and I can no longer right-click and run a single test method, doing that seems to run all test methods in the class...

Answer (score 6):

Recommended xUnit way to capture output is to use `ITestOutputHelper`:

```
public class BaseTestClass
{
    protected ITestOutputHelper Output { get; }

    public BaseTestClass(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        Output = output;
    }

    public void WriteLine(string str)
    {
        Output.WriteLine(str ?? Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

public class MyTestClass : BaseTestClass
{
    public MyTestClass(ITestOutputHelper output) : base(output) {}

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        WriteLine("foo");
    }
}
```

Check the docs: [Capturing Output](https://xunit.github.io/docs/capturing-output.html).

> If you used `xUnit.net 1.x`, you may have previously been writing output
>   to `Console`, `Debug`, or `Trace`. When `xUnit.net v2` shipped with
>   parallelization turned on by default, **this output capture mechanism
>   was no longer appropriate**; it is impossible to know which of the many
>   tests that could be running in parallel were responsible for writing
>   to those shared resources. Users who are porting code from v1.x to
>   v2.x should use one of the two new methods instead.

Comment: Thanks, this technically works to produce output for me, but I really don't want to use it.  I use `[TestClass]` and `[TestMethod]`.  When I switch to `[Fact]` and try to run an individual test method by right-clicking in code it runs all tests in that class.  Using the old attributes it complains that it can't find a default constructor and of course if I add one it doesn't set the output.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat, the problem is not in code. It is a test runner issue. Are you using Visual Studio runner? ReSharper test runner allows to run an individual test method. I use it by default.

Comment: I assume so, I always just create a unit test project in visual studio which creates a sample test class with the `[TestClass]` and `[TestMethod]` attributes.  I can run single tests that way by right-clicking inside the method and selecting to run or debug tests.  One of the nuget packages I had to install was `xunit.runner.visualstudio`.  When those attributes are not on the class (replace with `[Fact]`) and I right-click run a test it says I need to have a default constructor, and don't get the injected `ITestOutputHelper`.  I don't really know what it's using.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I even doesn't have `xunit.runner.visualstudio` package installed. The `[Fact]`-based code works fine in our day-to-day work with R#.